# method_added, when does it get called? How to call it?

Tags: ruby

I am confused on how and when method_added(method) gets called.

If I have

```
class Car

  def method_added(method)
    puts 'method added called'
    super
  end

  def one
    puts 'one method'
  end

  def two
    puts 'two method'
  end

end

Car.new.one
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: typo, specific to SO, issue is the same

Comment: Hint: what object do you add a method to? The `method_added` hook will be called on the object you are adding a method to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost straight from [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Module.html#method-i-method_added). Note this is plain Ruby, it is not a Rails thing.

```
class Car
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    puts "Adding #{method_name}"
  end

  def one
  end
end
# => Adding one
```

Comment: I expanded on my question because I did not initially explain the whole pattern.

Comment: Changed the question back to original, will post new one as it's a different issue.

Comment: Maybe the intro to the [Module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Module.html) doc helps.

Comment: Solved it. Your answer was very helpful. I missed it need to be a class method. Thank you,